# Interpretation of job status

Tags: mobile-application, status

I am currently working on a landscape mode mobile app, and one of the screens needs to show the state [active, paused, pending, completed] of the jobs.

In the following image I have added the icons for the states but do they represent the paused state or the user will think that he needs to tap it to pause the job.

What would be a better alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Avoid icon ambiguity wherever possible. In your scenario, a simple status string could work well for each row.

This could be done like so with color, or you could replace the "Completed: 0 / 99" with a status string instead. The icons remain in place to supplement the status.

*Please forgive the awful mockup.*

[image]